# PyQt Frame with text

Tags: python, widget, pyqt, pyqt4

Is there any `PyQt Widget` that is equivalent to `tkinter LabelFrame`?  Something like this

[image]

So far i only found `QtGui.QFrame` which doesn't seem to work the same way as `tkinter LabelFrame`. Am i missing something?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use QGroupBox for this purpose.

```
self.frame = QtGui.QGroupBox(self)    
self.frame.setTitle("Hello World")
```

Comment: Since  `QtGui.QGroupBox`only provides a frame around it with **some** styles, but not all, there should be a better solution around.